# Why is the 'if statement' getting ignored?

Tags: python, if-statement, printing

```
print("10 apples on a tree")
userChoice = input("Would you like to change the amount on apples ([Y]/[N]): ")

if userChoice == 'Y':
appleAmount = input("Please enter the amount of apples: ")

if appleAmount == 1:
    print("1 apple on a tree")
else:
    print(appleAmount, "apples on a tree")

if userChoice == 'N':
print("Okay.")
```

When ever I run my code, and enter '1'. It prints out "1 apples on a tree" instead of "1 apple on a tree" as I have wrote it. Struggling to pin point the problem.

My goal is, allowing the user to modify the amount of apples. If they decide to type in '1' then the word "apples" needs to change to "apple".

I have googled around and this is how everyone does the if statements but surely somethings wrong somewhere or have I missed something out.

Comment: `input()` returns a string value.  String `"1"` is not the same as integer `1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because of the indentation, also the type of `appleAmount` should be `int`:

```
print("10 apples on a tree")
userChoice = input("Would you like to change the amount on apples ([Y]/[N]): ")

if userChoice == 'Y':
    appleAmount = int(input("Please enter the amount of apples: "))

if appleAmount == 1:
    print("1 apple on a tree")
else:
    print(appleAmount, "apples on a tree")

if userChoice == 'N':
    print("Okay.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think it's because you're checking the integer `1` and not the string `"1"`. Returns from `input()` are strings, so either change them to integers to compare, or in this case just compare to the string version of `1`:

```py
print("10 apples on a tree")
userChoice = input("Would you like to change the amount on apples ([Y]/[N]): ")

if userChoice == 'Y':
    appleAmount = input("Please enter the amount of apples: ")

if appleAmount == "1":
    print("1 apple on a tree")
else:
    print(appleAmount, "apples on a tree")

if userChoice == 'N':
    print("Okay.")
```

Answer (score 0):

change this:

`if appleAmount == 1:`

to this:

`if int(appleAmount) == 1:`

`input()` returns a string, thats why the if statement is not working.